# Can you have a javascript conditional regex statement?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a basic understanding of regex.

I use javascript regex to filter some live chat comments, some of my statements stop the legitimate discussion.

This is because you are not allowed not discuss certain things in the open forum but you should be able to ask how much they are.

For example, I use the following to filter out comments that include the following words:

```regex
/(?=.*apple)|(\spear\s)|(banana)|(rasberry)/i
```

Is it possible to create a **regex** statement with a conditional element?

In summary, I would like to filter the string if it includes some words but not if it contains others, eg: “how much” or ”cost”?

Comment: It's probably going to be more efficient (and certainly easier to read) if you DON'T try to do this as a single RegExp - instead do it as you've described; check for one list of stop-words plus a second list. 
Short-cutting will mean that the second list doesn't get evaluated as often.

Comment: It's technically possible but very unfeasible, as you will have to keep adding more and more conditions to satisfy each word. Let's say if you don't want `banana` but `banana cost` is OK, then you also need to allow `cost of banana`. Not only that but you might need to account for any word distance between the two, `cost.*banana` and `banana.*cost` are a simpilification of what you'd need but you might need filters *for* the whitelist filters. And each whitelist item you add will explode into filters and filters for those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do in one regex, but you could definitely split it up like this:

```
// Check if regex matches
const containsWords = (str, reg) => {
  return reg.test(str)
}

const filteredRegex = /apple|spear|banana|rasberry/g
const allowedRegex = /how much|cost/g

// If the amount of matches is bigger than 0, check if it contains allowed words
if (containsWords(comment, filteredRegex)) {
  if (containsWords(comment, allowedRegex)) {
    // Allowed
  } else {
    // Not allowed
  }
}
```